# Is there a NonNullByDefault annotation for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, annotations

I am really missing @NonNullByDefault from eclipse in Android Studio. Is there a way to get this or something similar? I only saw one using javax's [@TypeQualifierDefault](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125281), but this seems not to be available in the android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just add the eclipse annotation package to your project and use it.

Simply add

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jdt', name: 'org.eclipse.jdt.annotation', version: '2.2.600'
}
```

To your gradle and you can use the @NonNullByDefault annotations it provides.

As usual you can either set it per class

```
@NonNullByDefault
public class MyClass {
    String test = "This is a non null string"
    @Nullable test2 = "This is a nullable string"

    public MyClass(String nonNullParam, @Nullable String nullableParam) {
        Object nonNullVar = nonNullParam;
        @Nullable Object nullableVar = nullableParam;
    }
}
```

Or you can set it for an entire package by creating a package-info.java file and in it

```
@NonNullByDefault   
package my.package;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault;
```

You still need to activate the setting in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35942944/2075537 to have complete coverage in case you forget it on a package

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a @NonNullByDefault functionality. BUT you can at least let the inspector handle all unannotated members & parameters as if they were annotated as @Nullable. Which will at least help to get 100% null-analyzation coverage. Basically a @NullByDefault.

[image: Inspector settings]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gradle script to handle **project-wide** **@NonNullByDefault** annotation for Android Studio.

It goes through all the subpackages to check whether *package-info.java* files are generated inside each of them.

The script is run before each assembleDebug task so that you can force @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault annotation **on all java classes in your project.**

[NonNullByDefault for all java classes inside a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084203/intellij-idea-parametersarenonnullbydefault-for-all-subpackages/40091450#40091450)