# IntelliJ IDEA @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault for all subpackages

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, nullable, non-nullable

I use IntelliJ's **null-checking mechanism** to prevent nullpointer crashes.
I've successfully set up all Java method parameters to be @NonNull by default using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13319541/706387) answer.

After creating *package-info.java* which is used to define [package annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/javadoc_tip_prefer_package_info) in Java. All java files which are direct descendants of that package have methods with default @NonNull parameters in my Android Studio project.

[image]

The obvious problem is that I need to define **@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault** for all Java classes in that package i.e. **including all subpackages**.

How can I define @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault so that it **propagates down to all subpackage java files**? I want to have all of my internal code's method annotated with @NonNull by default.

[image]

```
/**
  * File: package-info.java
  * Make all method parameters @NonNull by default
  */
  @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
  package com.intive.nearbyplaces.main;

  import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that I couldn't force Android Studio to respect **@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault** in all subpackages (i.e. recursively for all java files in *com.company.name*)

I wrote a **gradle script**, however, to check whether *package-info.java* files are generated inside each of the subpackage folders and create it if necessary. The script runs just before **assembleDebug** task.

So it turns out it is possible to force **@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault** annotation on all java classes in your project.

Download the source [here](https://gist.github.com/kosiara/233753e4de606eb5bd8b342209090e25). Remember to replace line 19 with **your package name**.

Usage:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: 'nonnull.gradle'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 24
   buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

   [...]
}
```

Remember to include *package-info.java* files in **.gitignore**

```
//File: .gitignore 

package-info.java
```

Checkstyle rule:

```
<module name="JavadocPackage"/>
```

checks whether package-info.java is included in each subpackage.

Source:

```
/**
 *  File: nonnull.gradle
 *
 *  Generates package-info.java for appropriate packages
 *  inside src/main/java folder.
 *
 *  This is a workaround to define @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault for all Java classes in a package
 *  i.e. including all subpackages (note: edit package name in line no. 19).
 */
task generateNonNullJavaFiles(dependsOn: "assembleDebug", type: Copy) {
    group = "Copying"
    description = "Generate package-info.java classes"

    def infoFileContentHeader = getFileContentHeader();
    def infoFileContentFooter = getFileContentFooter();

    def sourceDir = file( "${projectDir}" + File.separatorChar + "src" + File.separatorChar +
            "main" + File.separatorChar + "java" + File.separatorChar +
            "com" + File.separatorChar + "company" + File.separatorChar + "name" )
    sourceDir.eachDirRecurse { dir ->
        def infoFilePath = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + "package-info.java"

        if (!file(infoFilePath).exists()) {
            def infoFileContentPackage = getFileContentPackage(dir.getAbsolutePath());
            new File(infoFilePath).write(infoFileContentHeader +
                    infoFileContentPackage + infoFileContentFooter)
            println "[dir] " + infoFilePath + "  created";
        }
    }
    println "[SUCCESS] NonNull generator: package-info.java files checked"
}

def getFileContentPackage(path) {
    def mainSrcPhrase = "src" + File.separatorChar + "main" + File.separatorChar +
            "java" + File.separatorChar
    def mainSrcPhraseIndex = path.indexOf(mainSrcPhrase)
    def output = path.substring(mainSrcPhraseIndex)

    // Win hotfix
    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        output = output.replace("\\", "/")
        mainSrcPhrase = mainSrcPhrase.replace("\\", "/")
    }

    return "package " + output.replaceAll(mainSrcPhrase, "").replaceAll(
            "/", ".") + ";\n"
}

def getFileContentHeader() {
    return  "/** javadoc goes here \n */\n" +
            "@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault\n" +
            "@ReturnValuesAreNonnullByDefault\n"
}

def getFileContentFooter() {
    return  "\n" +
            "import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.ReturnValuesAreNonnullByDefault;"
}
```

Extended version which generates package info files for src main, test & androidTest folders can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/kosiara/44b4bf48f0b4bcf202b7c23ad02318de).

Findbugs & Lint:

It **does work** with findbugs & lint.

Comment: this is neat, but can't be used for Maven :(