# Check overall for Nonnull in Sonar using JSR305?

Tags: java, non-nullable, jsr305

I would like to check for possible null parameters, variables and return objects in Sonar. The Sonar we use do not support the jakarta annotations but it does support JSR305 javax annotations.

I could add `@Nonnull` annotations everywhere but that seems like a lot of boiler plate coding.

I could create a `package-info.java` file:

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package my.base.package;

import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;
```

And then only do explicit `@Nullable` where it is required.

But the `package-info` does not work for subpackages.

I come accross another [stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084203/intellij-idea-parametersarenonnullbydefault-for-all-subpackages) article from 7 years ago where a gradle script is used to duplicate the `package-info.java` files in every single directory that contains a java file.

This seems so much boiler plate again with files that I do not really want to see.

Is there no better way to do this?

Comment: Is the use of Sonar essential?  There are other tools like the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) that guarantees no null pointer exceptions and [NullAway](https://github.com/uber/NullAway) that prevents most null pointer exceptions.

Comment: @mernst thanks will check it out. Unfortunately I have to use Sonar as it is part of the enterprise standards.