# Set default annotation to @NonNull in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, annotations, nullable

I want to improve my Android projects with [Nullness annotations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#adding-nullness). I read that with the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-annotations) the `@NonNull` annotation is rarely written, because it is the default. This leads to much cleaner code since you only need to annotate the (hopefully) few types which are `@Nullable`.

Is it possible to set up Android Studio such that `@NonNull` is the default type?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084203/intellij-idea-parametersarenonnullbydefault-for-all-subpackages), but it seems overly complicated and it only does the parameters, so no return types and no fields.

Comment: Try to do as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35942944).

Answer (score 0):

You can use in android studio 3.0 up version.. in Analyze option you can find Infer Nullity option to set `@NonNull` or `@Nullable` automatically...

hope this helps..